# Suppose (1+$\lambda$)A = A+$\lambda$A. Why must A be convex?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A \subset \mathbb R^d$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.
Suppose $(1+\lambda)A = A+\lambda A$. Why must $A$ be convex?

If $x \in A+\lambda A$, then $x = a + \lambda a$ for some $a \in A$. Then, since $\mathbb R^d$ is a vector space, $a + \lambda a = (1+\lambda)a$. So $x \in (1+\lambda)A$.

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong with that argument.

Comment: $x \in A + \lambda A$ means $x = a + \lambda b$ for some $a,b \in A$, but $a$ and $b$ might be different.

Comment: you have proved $(1+\lambda)A\subset A+\lambda A$, you need now the other inclusion, i.e. $\exists c\mid (1+\lambda)c=a+\lambda b$

Comment: I think you need $\lambda>0$.  For example, if $\lambda=0$ then trivially $(1+\lambda)A = A = A + \lambda A$ for any (possibly nonconvex) set $A$.

Comment: I kinda like the case $\lambda=-1$ it leads to $A-A=0$ thus $A=\{a\}$ is a singleton thus convex!

Comment: You need it to hold for all $\lambda>0$. Otherwise, take $A={\Bbb Q}$ $\Rightarrow$ $A+A=2A$.

Comment: Thanks for all those comments; each one was helpful. I didn't realize $x \in A + \lambda A$ means that $x = a + \lambda b$ for some $a,b \in A$ rather than $x = a + \lambda a$ for some $a \in A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Partial result:*

Note that if $\lambda=0$ the equation is just $A=A$ so it brings no constrain on $A$.

$a+\lambda b=(\lambda+1)\bigg(\frac 1{\lambda+1}a+\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+1}b\bigg)=(\lambda+1)\bigg(ta+(1-t)b\bigg)$

with $t=\frac 1{\lambda+1}\in[0,1]$ (so you need hypothesis $\lambda>0$)

When $A$ is convex then $c=ta+(1-t)b\in A$ so $a+\lambda b=(1+\lambda)c$

And we have our inclusion $A+\lambda A\subset (1+\lambda)A$.

Convexity of $A$ is sufficient, but I'm not sure it is necessary...